# Maxima: replace function f(x) by its definition?

Tags: maxima

I cannot find anything about this, sorry.

If I have expressions with the symbolic function f(x) and now I want to replace in these expression f(x) by its explicit form how to do it?

For example:

I have

```
f(x):= x^2+sin(x)
```

and in the differentiation

```
diff (%e**sqrt(f(x)*a), x,2);
```

I want to replace now `f(x)` by the expression above?

Thanks

Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(%i1) i: integrate(f(x)*f(4*x), x, 0, 1) $

(%i2) f(x):= x^2+sin(x) $

(%i3) ev(i, f);
                     1
                    /
                    [             2                  2
(%o3)               I  (sin(x) + x ) (sin(4 x) + 16 x ) dx
                    ]
                    /
                     0
```

> ```
>  -- Function: ev (<expr>, <arg_1>, ..., <arg_n>)
>
>      Evaluates the expression <expr> in the environment specified by the
>      arguments <arg_1>, ..., <arg_n>.  The arguments are switches
>      (Boolean flags), assignments, equations, and functions.  'ev'
>      returns the result (another expression) of the evaluation.
> ```

Comment: many thanks, but for my problem this does not work. I have f(x):=exp(-x^2) and in the integral 'integrate (%f(x)*f(4*x), x, 0, 1) I want to replace f(x) now by exp(-x^ 2). How? Many thanks!

Comment: very sorry, we don't come together, i should have formulated more clearly, my fault.. I have 'integrate (%f(x)*f(4*x), x, 0, 1), please note the apostrophe and want that f(x) and f(4*x) are replaced by exp(-x^2) and exp(-(4*x)^ 2) as integrands, no evaluation.